# Is there a way to put requirements on hook dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Currently, I am checking if the `input` useEffect() hook dependency is at least a certain length before calling `loadSearchData()` which is an async method that hits an API.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (input.length >= MIN_CHAR_INPUT) {
      loadSearchData();
    }
  }, [input]);
```

Is there a way where I could move the input check to the `input` dependency param for useEffect()? Probably a case where I need to write a custom hook.

Comment: The current implementation seems reasonable barring the fact that `loadSearchData` may need parameters which might be affected from closure

Comment: More so just curious. However, `loadSearchData` is a wrapper for the function that gets all its params from the component state.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way where I could move the input check to the input dependency param for useEffect()? Probably a case where I need to write a custom hook.

I'd build it this way:

```
function useEffect2(effect, deps, isValid = true) {
  const cleanup = React.useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isValid) {
      if (typeof cleanup.current === "function") {
      // schedule cancellation of previous request right after effect has been called
      // using the Promise construct here so I don't have to deal with a throwing cancellation function
        Promise.resolve().then(cleanup.current);
      }

      // in case effect() throws, 
      // don't want to call the old cancellation function twice
      cleanup.current = null;
      // get new cancel-function
      cleanup.current = effect();
    }
  }, deps);

  useEffect(() => () => {
    // deal with cancellation on unmount
    typeof cleanup.current === "function" && cleanup.current();
  }, []);
}

useEffect2(loadSearchData, [input], input.length >= MIN_CHAR_INPUT);
```

> I just want to clarify the cancel. This will give us access to the current useEffect() call in the stack and allow us to properly handle the call without any memory-leaks

From https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#recap

> We’ve learned that useEffect lets us express different kinds of side effects after a component renders. Some effects might require cleanup so they return a function

*Cleanup is probably a better name. I use it the most to "cancel" previous ajax-requests if they are still pending/prevent them to update the state. I've renamed the variable in the code.*

What we're trying to emulate here is a `useEffect` that runs the effect conditionally. So when the condition is false, we don't want the effect to cleanup the previous call; as if the `deps` didn't change. Therefore we need to handle the cleanup function ourselves, and when/wether it should be invoked. That's

1. when *(and only if)* we call the effect function
2. on `componentWillUnmount`

That's what this `ref` is for. Since the reference is overwritten with every call to `effect` this shouldn't leak any memory.

Comment: I just want to clarify the `cancel`.  This will give us access to the current useEffect() call in the stack and allow us to properly handle the call without any memory-leaks?

Comment: @roasty it's not about accessing. It keeps track of the latest cancel/cleanup function returned by the effect and calls it when we're going to call `effect()` for the next time. I'm just trying to keep the behaviour as consistent to `useEffect` as possible.